# WebGL - animated sprites + animated coordinates

Tags: animation, glsl, webgl

I need to run both sprite animations and animated coordinates.

That is, a texture coordinate in [0, 1] is given for some specific sprite in an animation, and then it gets translated by another coordinate.

The translation can result in coordinates outside of [0, 1], and this is needed for repeating.

The problem is this - I supply the sprites as a texture atlas.
Therefore, selecting a sprite means getting a sub-rectangle in [0, 1].
Because this sprite is in between others, there is no way to get repeating - after all, if the texture coordinate moves outside of the sprite's rectangle, other sprites will be sampled.

The sprites are given in a texture atlas as a necessity - I am using instanced rendering, where each instance can use any sprite in the animation, and the only way to implement that, as far as I know, is with a texture atlas (or a texture array etc. in OpenGL).

tl;dr - is there a way to achieve both texture repeating, and sprite animations, in WebGL?

Comment: You could use an array that contains the texturecoordinates which will be used to animate the sprite by changing the index. Then use a modulo on the length of that array so it won't go outside the array and 'loops'. It is possible to put the texturecoordinates in a constant buffer and use an index in a attribute.

Comment: That's just how texture atlases work in general, read the question :P

Comment: _"The translation can result in coordinates outside of [0, 1]"_ sounds like you're translating the U,V coord them selves. Like I tried to write is; You should 'translate' the **index** within an array containing the U,V coords. Not the U,V coords. This way you never move the subrectangle to other sprites.   :P

Comment: I might not understand it correctly, but do you have some code? IMHO drawing a sprite animation should be done with an index as integer value. Using that int to calculate the appropriate UV by something like `newUV = firstFrameU + ((index % frame_count) * spriteWidth)` etc for horizontal.

Comment: Imagine if you have a static rectangle with a sprite animation running on it. What you wrote will get that working. Now let's say I want to also translate the animation in a repeating fashion. So let's say the sprite animation is a cloud, and I want many clouds (obviously many exactly spaced and same-animation running clouds look bad, but you get the idea :P), I would also need repeating, or texture coordinates outside of [0, 1]. However in the end, the sprites are a part of a larger texture, so going outside of [0, 1] (in relation to the sprite) inherently means sampling other sprites

Comment: The other option is of course to not have a single rectangle, but rather have one per animation-running cloud, however I do not have control over this aspect in this case

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know where the sprite is in the atlas then can't you just compute a texture coordinate modulo that range **in the fragment shader**?

```
vec2 animatedUV;      // animation value
vec2 spriteStartUV;   // corner uv coord for sprite in atlas
vec2 spriteEndVU;     // opposite corner uv coord for sprite in atlas

vec2 spriteRange = (spriteEndUV - spriteStartUV);
vec2 uv = spriteStartUV + fract(texcoord + animatedUV) * spriteRange;

vec4 color = texture2D(someTexture, uv);
```

Whether that works for your particular case I don't know but maybe it gives you some ideas.

Working example:

```js
const vs = `
void main() {
  // using a point sprite because it's easy but the concept 
  // is the same.
  gl_Position = vec4(0, 0, 0, 1);
  gl_PointSize = 40.0;
}
`;

const fs = `
precision mediump float;

// I'm passing these in as uniforms but you can pass them in as varyings
// from buffers if that fits your needs better

uniform vec2 animatedUV;      // animation value
uniform vec2 spriteStartUV;   // corner uv coord for sprite in atlas
uniform vec2 spriteEndUV;     // opposite corner uv coord for sprite in atlas

uniform sampler2D someTexture;

void main() {
  // this would normally come from a varying but lazy so using point sprite
  vec2 texcoord = gl_PointCoord.xy;  
  
  vec2 spriteRange = (spriteEndUV - spriteStartUV);
  vec2 uv = spriteStartUV + fract(texcoord + animatedUV) * spriteRange;

  vec4 color = texture2D(someTexture, uv);
  
  gl_FragColor = color;
}
`;

// use the canvas to make a texture atlas with one sprite
const ctx = document.querySelector("#atlas").getContext("2d");
const w = ctx.canvas.width;
const h = ctx.canvas.height
const sx = 30;
const sy = 40;
const sw = 50;
const sh = 60;
ctx.fillStyle = "red";
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, w, h);
ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
ctx.fillRect(sx, sy, sw, sh);
ctx.fillStyle = "yellow";
ctx.font = "45px sans-serif";
ctx.textAlign = "center";
ctx.textBaseline = "middle";
ctx.fillText("G", sx + sw / 2, sy + sh / 2);

// compute texcoods for sprite
const spriteStartUV = [ sx / w, sy / h ];
const spriteEndUV = [ (sx + sw) / w, (sy + sh) / h ];

const gl = document.querySelector("#webgl").getContext("webgl");
const programInfo = twgl.createProgramInfo(gl, [vs, fs]);

const tex = twgl.createTexture(gl, {
  src: ctx.canvas,
});

function render(time) {
  time *= 0.001;  // seconds
  gl.useProgram(programInfo.program);
  twgl.setUniforms(programInfo, {
    animatedUV: [time, time * 1.1],
    spriteStartUV: spriteStartUV,
    spriteEndUV: spriteEndUV,
    someTexture: tex,
  });
  gl.drawArrays(gl.POINTS, 0, 1);  // draw 1 point
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
}
requestAnimationFrame(render);
```

```css
canvas { border: 1px solid black; margin: 2px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://twgljs.org/dist/4.x/twgl.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="atlas"></canvas>
<canvas id="webgl"></canvas>
```

If you want it repeat more then increase your texcoords or add a multplier

```js
const vs = `
void main() {
  // using a point sprite because it's easy but the concept 
  // is the same.
  gl_Position = vec4(0, 0, 0, 1);
  gl_PointSize = 40.0;
}
`;

const fs = `
precision mediump float;

// I'm passing these in as uniforms but you can pass them in as varyings
// from buffers if that fits your needs better

uniform vec2 animatedUV;      // animation value
uniform vec2 spriteStartUV;   // corner uv coord for sprite in atlas
uniform vec2 spriteEndUV;     // opposite corner uv coord for sprite in atlas

uniform sampler2D someTexture;

void main() {
  // this would normally come from a varying but lazy so using point sprite
  vec2 texcoord = gl_PointCoord.xy * 3.;  // this * 3 could already be
                                          // in your texcoords
  
  vec2 spriteRange = (spriteEndUV - spriteStartUV);
  vec2 uv = spriteStartUV + fract(texcoord + animatedUV) * spriteRange;

  vec4 color = texture2D(someTexture, uv);
  
  gl_FragColor = color;
}
`;

// create texture atlas with one sprite
const ctx = document.querySelector("#atlas").getContext("2d");
const w = ctx.canvas.width;
const h = ctx.canvas.height
const sx = 30;
const sy = 40;
const sw = 50;
const sh = 60;
ctx.fillStyle = "red";
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, w, h);
ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
ctx.fillRect(sx, sy, sw, sh);
ctx.fillStyle = "yellow";
ctx.font = "45px sans-serif";
ctx.textAlign = "center";
ctx.textBaseline = "middle";
ctx.fillText("G", sx + sw / 2, sy + sh / 2);

// compute texture coords for sprite in atlas
const spriteStartUV = [ sx / w, sy / h ];
const spriteEndUV = [ (sx + sw) / w, (sy + sh) / h ];

const gl = document.querySelector("#webgl").getContext("webgl");
const programInfo = twgl.createProgramInfo(gl, [vs, fs]);

const tex = twgl.createTexture(gl, {
  src: ctx.canvas,
});

function render(time) {
  time *= 0.001;  // seconds
  gl.useProgram(programInfo.program);
  twgl.setUniforms(programInfo, {
    animatedUV: [time, time * 1.1],
    spriteStartUV: spriteStartUV,
    spriteEndUV: spriteEndUV,
    someTexture: tex,
  });
  gl.drawArrays(gl.POINTS, 0, 1);  // draw 1 point
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
}
requestAnimationFrame(render);
```

```css
canvas { border: 1px solid black; margin: 2px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://twgljs.org/dist/4.x/twgl.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="atlas"></canvas>
<canvas id="webgl"></canvas>
```

note the sample above uses uniforms but you could just as easily use per vertex spriteStartUV, spriteEndUV and any other data using attributes and adding that data to your buffers.

### update

Example with more sprites to make it clearer it's using a texture atlas

```js
const vs = `
uniform vec4 u_position;
void main() {
  // using a point sprite because it's easy but the concept 
  // is the same.
  gl_Position = u_position;
  gl_PointSize = 40.0;
}
`;

const fs = `
precision mediump float;

// I'm passing these in as uniforms but you can pass them in as varyings
// from buffers if that fits your needs better

uniform vec2 animatedUV;      // animation value
uniform vec2 spriteStartUV;   // corner uv coord for sprite in atlas
uniform vec2 spriteEndUV;     // opposite corner uv coord for sprite in atlas

uniform sampler2D someTexture;

void main() {
  // this would normally come from a varying but lazy so using point sprite
  vec2 texcoord = gl_PointCoord.xy * 3.;  // this * 3 could already be
                                          // in your texcoords
  
  vec2 spriteRange = (spriteEndUV - spriteStartUV);
  vec2 uv = spriteStartUV + fract(texcoord + animatedUV) * spriteRange;

  vec4 color = texture2D(someTexture, uv);
  
  gl_FragColor = color;
}
`;

// create texture atlas with 36 sprites
const ctx = document.querySelector("#atlas").getContext("2d");
const w = ctx.canvas.width;
const h = ctx.canvas.height;
ctx.fillStyle = "red";
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, w, h);

const sw = 16;
const sh = 16;
const spritesAcross = w / sw | 0;
const spriteData = [];
const backgroundColors = [
  "#884", "#848", "#488", "#448", "#484", "#488", "#222",
];
"ABCDEFGHIIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789".split('').forEach((letter, ndx) => {
  const sx = ndx % spritesAcross * sw;   
  const sy = (ndx / spritesAcross | 0) * sh;
  ctx.fillStyle = backgroundColors[ndx % backgroundColors.length];
  ctx.fillRect(sx, sy, sw, sh);
  ctx.fillStyle = "yellow";
  ctx.font = "16px sans-serif";
  ctx.textAlign = "center";
  ctx.textBaseline = "middle";
  ctx.fillText(letter, sx + sw / 2, sy + sh / 2);
  spriteData.push({
    spriteStartUV: [ sx / w, sy / h ],
    spriteEndUV: [ (sx + sw) / w, (sy + sh) / h ],
  });
});

// compute texture coords for sprite in atlas
const gl = document.querySelector("#webgl").getContext("webgl");
const programInfo = twgl.createProgramInfo(gl, [vs, fs]);

const tex = twgl.createTexture(gl, {
  src: ctx.canvas,
});

function render(time) {
  time *= 0.001;  // seconds
  gl.useProgram(programInfo.program);
  for (let i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
    const spriteInfo = spriteData[i % spriteData.length];
    const t = time + i;
    twgl.setUniforms(programInfo, {
      u_position: [Math.sin(t * 1.2), Math.sin(t * 1.3), 0, 1],
      animatedUV: [t, t * 1.1],
      spriteStartUV: spriteInfo.spriteStartUV,
      spriteEndUV: spriteInfo.spriteEndUV,
      someTexture: tex,
    });
    gl.drawArrays(gl.POINTS, 0, 1);  // draw 1 point
  }
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
}
requestAnimationFrame(render);
```

```css
canvas { border: 1px solid black; margin: 2px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://twgljs.org/dist/4.x/twgl.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="atlas"></canvas>
<canvas id="webgl"></canvas>
```

Comment: Generally speaking that would work, however it stops repeating from happening!

Comment: Are you sure the complete animation is sequential in that texture on a horizontal/vertical range?

Comment: I generate the texture atlas and control it fully, if that's what you mean. The issue is that the repeating wrap mode cannot be emulated to the best of my knowledge, and sprite animation can only be achieved with a texture atlas. It might be impossible to implement without WebGL2 that supports texture arrays.

Comment: To understand why repeating can't be emulated - imagine a simple static rectangle, with a texture mapped to it that keeps being translated, e.g. a cloud in the sky. Now increase the texture coordinates, and you get multiple clouds. The moment you disable repeating, it's impossible to emulate it, because you just have those 4 corners.

Comment: I'm confused why you think repeat doesn't work. Added an example

Comment: Try a texture atlas with more than one sprite, the code you posted is just a normal texture with repeating, not a texture atlas. :)

Comment: It's sprite atlas with one sprite. Add more sprites it will still work. That's why I put the sprite in the middle of the texture and gave it a blue background while there rest of the texture is red, to show that it's only using the blue area of the texture atlas. Add more images to the texture it will work just fine.

Comment: Your example works because you compute the texture coordinates in the fragment shader. I didn't think about doing that. It's obviously less ideal than doing so in the vertex shader. Regardless, this might indeed be the only answer using WebGL 1.

Comment: Can you edit the answer so it states that difference? Just because computing in the vertex shader is so standard. Thanks!

Comment: No idea why you think it's less than ideal doing it in the fragment shader. manipulating texture coordinates in a fragment shader is used in tons of shaders, maybe the most common being parallax mapping.